Hausdorffness of mapping space, implies Hausdorffness of codomain
I am trying to prove following:
Let Y be a topological space and $Top(X,Y)$ the space of all continuous functions from an arbitrary topological space $X\neq \emptyset$ into $Y$. If $Top(X,Y)$ equipped with the compact-open topology $Top^{co}(X,Y)$ is a Hausdorff space, we know Y is also a Hausdorff space.
My attempt goes as follows:
Let $Top^{co}(X,Y)$ be a Hausdorff space, for arbitrary topological space X. Furthermore let $x,y \in Y$ and $x \neq y$, note $c_x,c_y \in Top^{co}(X,Y) $, for $c_x(X)=\{x\}$ and $c_y(X)=\{y\}$, since constant functions, are always continuous. Now, we know there are open and disjoint neighborhoods U of $c_x$ and V of $c_y$. It is known that for $K \subset X$ compact and $U \subset Y$ open; sets of the form $M(K,U)=\{f\in Top^{co}(X,Y) | f(K) \subset U\}$ form a subasis of $Top^{co}(X,Y)$. So $U=\bigcup_\limits{i \in I}\bigcap_\limits{p_i=1}^{n_i}M(K_{p_i}, U_{p_i})$ and $V=\bigcup_\limits{j \in J}\bigcap_\limits{q_j=1}^{m_j}M(L_{q_j}, V_{q_j})$, for $K_{p_i}, L_{q_j}, U_{p_i}, V_{q_j}$ as above.
I am pretty sure for the open and disjoint neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$ we just take $\bigcup_\limits{i \in I}\bigcap_\limits{p_i=1}^{n_i}U_{p_i}=:U‘$ for $x$ and $\bigcup_\limits{j \in J}\bigcap_\limits{q_j=1}^{m_j}U_{q_j}=:V‘$ for $y$. That $U‘$ and $V‘$ are indeed open neighborhoods follows by construction and the definition of open sets. My problem is, I do not see why $U‘$ and $V‘$, would be disjoint. I already tried to show, that if $U$ and $V$ are just a mere intersection of finite subabasis elements, that the analogous open neighborhoods would be disjoint, but even there I failed. I would gladly appreciate any help or ideas!

Nitpick: You should explicitly state that you assume $X \neq \emptyset$.

Here's another approach: Consider the function $\newcommand{\Top}{\operatorname{Top}^{\mathrm{co}}}\phi\colon Y \to \Top(X, Y)$ given by $\phi(y) = c_y$, the constant function at $y$. Clearly $\phi$ is injective, and it is also continuous since
\begin{align}
    \phi^{-1}(M(K, U)) &= \phi^{-1}(\{f \in \Top(X, Y) \mid f(K) \subseteq U\}) \\
        &= \phi^{-1}(\{c_y \mid y \in U\}) \\
        &= U
\end{align}
for any $K \subseteq X$ compact and $U \subset Y$ open and it suffices to check continuity on a subbasis.
I'll leave it to you to fill in the details for showing that a continuous injection into a Hausdorff space has Hausdorff domain.
